# Python Modular scripting include another script

Tags: python, module, include, modular

Need to make a container app that will run different configurations of modules.
i.e. container app is A, inside A i can add B that is another script that count, else I can add C that is a script that read a value.

would it be possible with imports? what's the best practice to do it?

```
A = run a while cicle
B = run some functions
c = run another set of functions
```

A.py

```
a=0
while 1:
    import B
    import C
```

B.py

```
def pippo():
    print a=a+1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pippo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do it like this

In A.py

```
import B
import C
a = 0
while True:
    B.do_something()
    C.do_anotherthing()
```

In B.py

```
def do_something():
    "Do Your Stuff"
```

In C.py

```
def do_anotherthing():
    "Do your another Stuff"
```